# What is the intuition behind quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

It has long irked me that quantum mechanics appears to be so bound up in mysticism, if that isn't too strong a word.

It shouldn't be like that: it should be possible to follow the reasoning all the way back to some intuitively obvious axioms - "intuitively obvious" , at least if you invest enough in understanding the mathematics.

The way I was introduced to quantum mechanics years ago, it went something like: "First, you calculate the Hamiltonian, then *mumble mumble* and then you have the Hamiltonian Operator". I have never come across a good, intuitive explanation for why we should expect the apparently magical process of translating the classical Hamiltonian to an operator on (a dense subset of) a Hilbert space, $L^2(R^d)$, to work.

Where did the idea come from, that the physical state of a system should be described by a complex-valued "wave-function" and the observables are differential operators that act on wave-functions - and what was the intuitive reasoning behind? What is the mathematical justification - other than "it seems to work"?

The maths don't scare me - I have some understanding of manifolds, bundles, Lie algebras and -groups, I understand that wave-functions are sections of the base manifold into the complex line bundle and that you can, locally, consider them simply to be complex valued functions.

Comment: I don't think that anyone, neither physicist nor mathematician, really knows why quantization works. As I've understood it, quantization isn't even well-defined; there might be several ways to quantize a given classical Lagrangian, but not all ways work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might enjoy [Todorov's 2012 classic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3116). As his Nelson quip summarizes, it is *not a functor*. Given a classical hamiltonian phase-space function, there are several "prescriptions" or "recipes" that yield the same operator-on-Hilbert-space answer. But, of course, there are counterexamples, which are a source of an almost century-old fascination. There is no "should". By ingenuity, luck, and trial-and-error, superheroes in the 1920s stumbled on it, and were pleased to note nature listened.

The cited article reminds you why, for flat geometry phase spaces the answers agree. Half of your problem is cultural: you are asked to compare and contrast theories defined in phase space and Hilbert space, respectively. There is a wonderful (but computationally demanding/barely-tractable) formulation of [quantum mechanics in phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) which eliminates the culture problem and permits comparison and contrast of apples with apples. (But it assumes you are familiar with concepts of the Hilbert space/oranges formulation, really... Take a look at [this introduction](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf).)

The engine of this purely formal map from Hilbert space to phase space is the [Wigner map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_transform), with an inverse  given by the Weyl map.

Using the Weyl map, you may go from a classical hamiltonian to a unique quantum one, *but*, contrary to Weyl's 1927 wild guess, it is *not* superior, except computationally. By trial and error, people have discovered systems whose hamiltonian is *not* the Weyl image of a classical hamiltonian, and, in fact, physical systems with *different* hamiltonians, whose Wigner maps all have the *same* $\hbar\to 0$ classical hamiltonian limit.

So, as Todorov quips: "Quantization is a mystery".

Comment: Hi Cosmas - this is something like what I was hoping for. I will inspect the links and probably accept your answer after that. I really want to feel that I "understand" quantisation - you say that there is no "should", but I think there should be ;-) I believe that it is only by understanding quantisation, that we can repair whatever is broken between QM and GR. A question that is probably related: what happens to quantisation if space-time is far from being flat?

Comment: Indeed, quantization in curved spaces is an active area of research... a mystery....

Comment: I have decided to accept your answer - it doesn't quite scratch my itch, but it is probably the closest one can get at the moment. The various QM axioms seem too constructed, as if they were fashioned merely to fit the observations and in effect sweep the hard questions under the carpet; I feel we need to think bigger - QM and GR are both too fundamental to simply try to bend one to fit the other. One line of thinking I think holds some promise is see what can be achieved with some sort of geometry of topological spaces with weaker separation, which may accomodate 'spooky action'.

Comment: Sorry, comments are too small to provide real details.